# jar dependencies Maven

Tags: maven, jar

I am a beginner, I'd worked with Maven to manage my dependencies and no look for get the jar on the internet then added the classPath project.

Currently I'm working with program that has attacked a database so I need to work with hibernat but at my level I do not know where I can find groupId and artifactId for Hibernate. if someone have ideas or track let me know and I'd be really grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/) to search artifacts. And there is a quick link for Hibernate there at the very top of the home page:

[image: MvnRepository]

Answer (score 0):

follow the below which i have provided

```
http://geeklabs.co.in/mvn/smpmvnapp_eclipse.html
```